# Python - how to write multiple lines to a file? (list, not string)

Tags: python-3.x, list, web-scraping, beautifulsoup, file-writing

I cannot for the life of me figure out how to get the elements of this list, which are lists themselves, to print in multiple lines when I write them to the file. I scrape the titles from the website, and I scrape the links. the end goal (for your insight) is to pair the titles and links in a format like so:

```
<a href='www.mywebsite.com/curry-recipe'>Curry Recipe<a/>
```

But for now, the problem is that while I end up with desfinalList looking alright, for example:

```
[['Curry Recipe', 'www.originalwebsite.com/curry-recipe'], ['Pancake Recipe', 'www.originalwebsite.com/pancake-recipe']]
```

I can't seem to print it into the file without it all going into one massive line. with text wrapping, it's manageable visibly but I'd prefer it be on multiple lines.

The offending code is the very last block.

```
def OFDdesserts():

    urlA = 'https://olivesfordinner.com/category/dessert/page/{}'

    for i in range(2,5): 
        url = urlA.format(i)
    
        response = requests.get(url)
        htmlText = response.text
    
        soup = BeautifulSoup(htmlText, 'lxml')
        links = soup.find_all('article')

        for title in links[0:12]:
            titleActual = title.get('aria-label')
            if 'Giveaway' not in titleActual:
                hyperL = title.find('header', class_ = 'entry-header').a['href']
                if titleActual not in desTitleList:
                    desTitleList.append(titleActual)
                    desLinkList.append(hyperL)


    desList3.append([[x,y] for x,y in zip(desTitleList, desLinkList)])

    #erase duplicates
    for item in desList3:
        if item not in desfinalList:
            desfinalList.append(item) 

    #write the file
    for elem in desfinalList:
        with open('recipes/desserts.txt', 'w') as f:
            f.write('\n \n'.join(map(str, desfinalList)))
            print('just added something yummy to desserts!')
```

Comment: your code works fine for me. the example list of lists creates a file with a blank line between the two lists. I'm on windows PC, if that makes a difference. You sure the example you provided is what you're really dealing with?

Comment: yep, i copied and pasted

Answer (score 0):

it better to use `.select()` method, it selector like jQuery or CSS and use `str()` to get the link as html `<a href="....">anchor</a>`.

```
def OFDdesserts():
    urlA = 'https://...../page/{}'
    linkTags = []

    for i in range(2,5): 
        url = urlA.format(i)
        response = requests.get(url)
        soup = BeautifulSoup(response.text, 'html.parser')
        links = soup.select('.content article h2 a')

        for link in links:
            if 'Giveaway' in link.text:
                continue
            # clean tag (i) from anchor text
            link.extract()
            # clean link attributes
            link.attrs = {'href': link.attrs['href']}
            linkStr = str(link)
            if linkStr not in linkTags:
                linkTags.append(linkStr)

    #write the file
    with open('desserts.txt', 'w') as f:
        f.write('\n\n'.join(linkTags))
        print('just added something yummy to desserts!')
```